# How do i make a class with same constructor with different name?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a code here which creates a moveknight class object.
I have two object with same name called knight, but each of these knight have different string name:

```
int main() {
    int x;
    //Tree tree(1000, 1000);
//  Node start(3,3);
    //Node end(2,2);
    moveknight knight("Sigma");
    moveknight knight("Lamda");
    x = knight("Sigma").Minimum_Steps(8,8,2,2,4,4);
    //start.print_root();

    cout << x << endl;
    //cout << end << endl;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Can a same class object have different "String" name to be considered a different object?

I want knight("Sigma") and knight("Lambda") to be different objects.

Comment: Name them `knightSigma` and `knightLambda`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have two object with same name called `knight`

That won't work.  You can't have multiple variables with the same name in the same scope.  You need to rename them, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int x;
    //Tree tree(1000, 1000);
//  Node start(3,3);
    //Node end(2,2);
    moveknight Sigma("Sigma");
    moveknight Lamda("Lamda");
    x = Sigma.Minimum_Steps(8,8,2,2,4,4);
    //start.print_root();

    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    //std::cout << end << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to refer to objects by name strings, use `std::(unordered_)map` for that, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main() {
    int x;
    //Tree tree(1000, 1000);
//  Node start(3,3);
    //Node end(2,2);
    std::map<std::string, moveknight> knight;
    knight["Sigma"] = moveknight("Sigma");
    knight["Lamda"] = moveknight("Lamda");
    x = knight["Sigma"].Minimum_Steps(8,8,2,2,4,4);
    //start.print_root();

    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    //std::cout << end << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```